# Reusable function to group_by but return an object with group as key

Tags: json, group-by, jq

This question is looking for a reusable function that can be imported into other jq programs. The question [group and key by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221453/jq-group-and-key-by-property) is addressing a specific problem. This question is aimed to be as general as possible, since this is a recurring problem.

Given the following (sample) input, how can I create a new object which groups together each person by their country? I know about `group_by`, but it returns an array of arrays.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "anna",
    "country": "germany"
  },
  {
    "name": "lisa",
    "country": "germany"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "country": "usa"
  }
]
```

Running `group_by(.country)` produces:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "name": "anna",
      "country": "germany"
    },
    {
      "name": "lisa",
      "country": "germany"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "country": "usa"
    }
  ]
]
```

but this structure makes subsequent processing difficult. Instead, I'd prefer to transform the document into the following structure:

```json
{
  "germany": [
    {
      "name": "anna",
      "country": "germany"
    },
    {
      "name": "lisa",
      "country": "germany"
    }
  ],
  "usa": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "country": "usa"
    }
  ]
}
```

This would make other tasks such as counting persons per country a lot easier.

How can I do it? If possible, the answer should not rely on the exact format of the sample format, but be applicable in the general case for arbitrary inputs.

Comment: How can this question be improved? What makes it a bad question?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a reusable function which groups an array by a criteria and uses this criteria as key. Obviously, this will only work for string keys (but one can always add `|tostring`).

```
def group(k):
  group_by(k) | map({ key: first|k, value: . }) | from_entries;
```

Transforming to the expected output is then simply:

```
group(.country)
```

Additional tasks such as counting persons per country then become trivial:

```
group(.country) | map_values(length)
```

produces:

```json
{
  "germany": 2,
  "usa": 1
}
```

Chaining other transformations is straightforward too with this helper function. Need a list of names per country?

```
group(.country) | map_values(map(.name))
```

voilà

```json
{
  "germany": [
    "anna",
    "lisa"
  ],
  "usa": [
    "john"
  ]
}
```

---

It might be beneficial to map the values in one go. This can be achieved with a second parameter. The original function can now be redefined to delegate to the more general function:

```
def group(k;v):
  group_by(k) | map({ key: first|k, value: map(v) }) | from_entries;
def group(k): group(k; .);
```

```
group(.country; .name)
```

---

To allow arbitrary objects to be used to group objects, the function needs a second parameter which will then convert the group into a string key.

```
def group(group;key):
  group_by(group) | map({key:first|group|key, value:.}) | from_entries;
def group(group): group(group; .);
```

Special attention needs to be paid that the string representation of the group must have a 1:1 mapping with the group, otherwise some items will be lost in the `from_entries` step.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant using `reduce` instead of `group_by`:

```bash
reduce .[] as $m ({}; .[$m.country] += [$m])
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sVVuSWg_ozX)

Or as a defined function:

```bash
def grp(f): reduce .[] as $m ({}; .[$m|f] += [$m]);

grp(.country)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UuP84ectvoy)

```json
{
  "germany": [
    {
      "name": "anna",
      "country": "germany"
    },
    {
      "name": "lisa",
      "country": "germany"
    }
  ],
  "usa": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "country": "usa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter alternative using `group_by`, `map()` and [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add):

```
group_by(.country) | map({ (.[0].country): . }) | add
```

Produces:

```json
{
  "germany": [
    {
      "name": "anna",
      "country": "germany"
    },
    {
      "name": "lisa",
      "country": "germany"
    }
  ],
  "usa": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "country": "usa"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Jq{Play](https://jqplay.org/s/NUlHKffWrCv)

Comment: What does `[.[]]` do? Isn't that just `.` since it first streams the array's value to eventually wrap them in a new array again?

Comment: Yep, you're right, just `.` is fine.

Comment: I never know if one should use `.[0]` or `first`, but I guess that's just personal preference?

Comment: Yep, doesn't matter. Looking at [JQ source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/a9f97e9e61a910a374a5d768244e8ad63f407d3e/src/builtin.jq#L187), it's defined as: `def first: .[0];`