# How to use jq reduce to sort array into an object

Tags: jq

I am trying to reduce an array

```json
  [
  {"cat": "low", "value": "1"},
  {"cat": "med", "value": "2"},
  {"cat": "med", "value": "3"}
  ]
```

such that it produces this output:

```json
{
  "low": [
    {
      "cat": "low",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ],
  "med": [
    {
      "cat": "med",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "cat": "med",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

### jq code

I tried this jq code:

```
reduce .[] as $curr ({}; 
                     $curr.cat as $category |                         # store the current category, eg "low"
                     .[$category] as $currArray |                     # store the current array that eg "low" points to
                     $currArray + [($curr)] as $newCategoryArray |    # add the current object to the current array
                     . + {($category): ($newCategoryArray)}           # use object addition to update the accumulator
                    )
```

### Error

however I am getting the error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:5): array ([{"cat":"me...) and object ({"low":[{"c...) cannot be added
exit status 5
```

Any help is appreciated.

jq snippet here: https://jqplay.org/s/HL0r2CqewAr

#### Notes:

If possible, could someone also explain why my reducer is throwing the error. I have simplified my problem so an explanation would help me greatly.

Removing an item from the input array, jq is able to run successfully.

The error is only encountered when the 'category' is not unique.

eg, this input parses without any error

```json
  [
  {"cat": "low", "value": "1"},
  {"cat": "med", "value": "2"}
  ]
```

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text

Comment: Does this help? [Function to group_by but return an object with group as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893818/function-to-group-by-but-return-an-object-with-group-as-key) – effectively `jq 'group(.cat)'` ("group" is a custom function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `reduce`, add the items to and as an array:

```bash
jq 'reduce .[] as $curr ({}; .[$curr.cat] += [$curr])'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nyvM9IBMuzu)

Alternatively, you can use `group_by`, then `add` the `map`ped items:

```bash
jq 'group_by(.cat) | map({(first.cat): .}) | add'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WcMsDqZ4uuu)

The same can be achieved using `with_entries`:

```bash
jq 'group_by(.cat) | with_entries(.key = .value[0].cat)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Qp-yPO-P4Xx)

Or even shorter, using `INDEX`:

```bash
jq 'group_by(.cat) | INDEX(first.cat)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0pSJ5VzKb8-)

```json
{
  "low": [
    {
      "cat": "low",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ],
  "med": [
    {
      "cat": "med",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "cat": "med",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks! have never used group_by before ... interesting ... I would also appreciate if possible an explanation of why my reducer threw the error in the first place ...

Comment: @tg0h You tried to use `as` on an expression but it only bound the last part. Use parens, and it'll work as well: `($currArray + [($curr)]) as $newCategoryArray`

Comment: ahh spent 2 hours scratching my head on that. thanks again!