# Using jq, how to split OpenAPI 3.0 file into chunks based on the tag property?

Tags: jq, openapi

I've got something challenging (at least for me) to do. There is this OpenAPI 3.0 file that needs some dicing based on the tags (i.e. cut into as many chunks as there are items in the `tags` property.

For simplicity, there 2 tags in this example.
So, all the `paths` that belong to the **Rotor Parts** tag will go into the first dictionary item. And other parts will go under the second dictionary item.

Here's the input file:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "PREST APIs for external use.",
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "REST API Doc",
    "contact": {},
    "license": {
      "name": "Public"
    }
  },
  "tags":[
      {
        "name": "Rotor Parts",
        "description": "Rotor Parts API"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cloud Accounts",
        "description": "Plant Locations APIs"
      }
    ],
  "paths": {
    "/access_keys": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Rotor Parts"
        ],
        "summary": "List Rotor Parts",
        "description": "Returns all rotor parts if you have an Admin role. Returns just your rotor parts if you don't have this role.",
        "operationId": "get-my-rotor-parts",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RotorPartsResponseModel"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "user_inactive_or_not_exist"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "unauthorized_to_use_rotor_parts"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "failed_fetch_user_profile"
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Rotor Parts"
        ],
        "summary": "Add Rotor Parts",
        "description": "Adds a new rotor part for the current user. If you have API access, you can create up to two rotor parts.",
        "operationId": "add-rotor-parts",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserRotorPartRequestModel"
              }
            }
          },
          "description": "Model user rotor part model",
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateUserAccessKeyResponseModel"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_expiry_access_key / already_have_two_access_keys / invalid_access_key_name_length / invalid_access_key_name"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "unauthorized_to_use_access_keys"
          },
          "409": {
            "description": "duplicate_access_key_name"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/account/{accountId}/config/status": {
    "get": {
      "tags": [
        "Cloud Accounts"
      ],
      "summary": "List Account Status Details",
      "description": "Returns a list of Cloud services whose status indicates a warning or error for the given cloud account ID. Includes status details for each listed service.",
      "operationId": "list-cloud-account-status-details",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "accountId",
          "in": "path",
          "description": "Cloud account ID",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "successful operation",
          "content": {
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CloudAccountConfigStatusView"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "400": {
          "description": "bad_request"
        },
        "500": {
          "description": "internal_error"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

And here's an expected output:

```
{
  "tag_RotorParts": {
    "info": "same content here",
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Rotor Parts",
        "description": "Rotor Parts API"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "/access_keys": {
        "get": {
          "tags": [
            "Rotor Parts"
          ],
          "summary": "List Rotor Parts",
          "description": "Returns all rotor parts if you have an Admin role. Returns just your rotor parts if you don't have this role.",
          "operationId": "get-my-rotor-parts",
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RotorPartsResponseModel"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "user_inactive_or_not_exist"
            },
            "403": {
              "description": "unauthorized_to_use_rotor_parts"
            },
            "500": {
              "description": "failed_fetch_user_profile"
            }
          }
        },
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Rotor Parts"
          ],
          "summary": "Add Rotor Parts",
          "description": "Adds a new rotor part for the current user. If you have API access, you can create up to two rotor parts.",
          "operationId": "add-rotor-parts",
          "requestBody": {
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserRotorPartRequestModel"
                }
              }
            },
            "description": "Model user rotor part model",
            "required": true
          },
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateUserAccessKeyResponseModel"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "invalid_expiry_access_key / already_have_two_access_keys / invalid_access_key_name_length / invalid_access_key_name"
            },
            "403": {
              "description": "unauthorized_to_use_access_keys"
            },
            "409": {
              "description": "duplicate_access_key_name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tag_CloudAccounts": "Same Format as above"
}
```

So far, I've tried using `reduce` to achieve this:

```
. as $all |  reduce .tags as $tag  ({}; . + {"tag_" + $tag.name: (($all.paths) | select(.[][].tags | contains([$tag.name]))) })
```

But can't even make the query valid. Really lost at this point.

Any help/pointers much appreciated

Comment: Each path only has a single tag? Or can they have multiple tags? Should they then be duplicated for each tag?

Comment: 1) Consider using an [OpenAPI parser](https://openapi.tools/#parsers) instead. 2) Also keep the $refs in mind. Components (schemas, parameters, responses, etc.) referenced by a specific operation need to be put in the same file so that local $refs in the format `$ref: '#/components/...'` remain valid; otherwise the $ref paths must be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array of key-value pairs based on the `.tags` array, which you can eventually convert to an object using `from_entries`. Use `del` to delete what you don't want to be included.

```bash
[.tags[] as $tag | {key: "tag_\($tag.name | gsub(" "; ""))", value: del(
  
  .openapi,
  (.tags[] | select(. != $tag)),
  (.paths[] | select(IN(.[].tags[]; $tag.name) | not))
  
)}] | from_entries
```

```json
{
  "tag_RotorParts": {
    "info": {
      "description": "Prisma Cloud REST APIs for external use.",
      "version": "v1",
      "title": "Prisma Cloud REST API Doc",
      "contact": {},
      "license": {
        "name": "Public"
      }
    },
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Rotor Parts",
        "description": "Rotor Parts API"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "/access_keys": {
        "get": {
          "tags": [
            "Rotor Parts"
          ],
          "summary": "List Rotor Parts",
          "description": "Returns all rotor parts if you have an Admin role. Returns just your rotor parts if you don't have this role.",
          "operationId": "get-my-rotor-parts",
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RotorPartsResponseModel"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "user_inactive_or_not_exist"
            },
            "403": {
              "description": "unauthorized_to_use_rotor_parts"
            },
            "500": {
              "description": "failed_fetch_user_profile"
            }
          }
        },
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Rotor Parts"
          ],
          "summary": "Add Rotor Parts",
          "description": "Adds a new rotor part for the current user. If you have API access, you can create up to two rotor parts.",
          "operationId": "add-rotor-parts",
          "requestBody": {
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserRotorPartRequestModel"
                }
              }
            },
            "description": "Model user rotor part model",
            "required": true
          },
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "content": {
                "application/json": {
                  "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateUserAccessKeyResponseModel"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "invalid_expiry_access_key / already_have_two_access_keys / invalid_access_key_name_length / invalid_access_key_name"
            },
            "403": {
              "description": "unauthorized_to_use_access_keys"
            },
            "409": {
              "description": "duplicate_access_key_name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tag_CloudAccounts": {
    "info": {
      "description": "Prisma Cloud REST APIs for external use.",
      "version": "v1",
      "title": "Prisma Cloud REST API Doc",
      "contact": {},
      "license": {
        "name": "Public"
      }
    },
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Cloud Accounts",
        "description": "Plant Locations APIs"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "/account/{accountId}/config/status": {
        "get": {
          "tags": [
            "Cloud Accounts"
          ],
          "summary": "List Account Status Details",
          "description": "Returns a list of Cloud services whose status indicates a warning or error for the given cloud account ID. Includes status details for each listed service.",
          "operationId": "list-cloud-account-status-details",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "accountId",
              "in": "path",
              "description": "Cloud account ID",
              "required": true,
              "schema": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          ],
          "responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "content": {
                "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                  "schema": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CloudAccountConfigStatusView"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "400": {
              "description": "bad_request"
            },
            "500": {
              "description": "internal_error"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ds7oUHkSaf8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that looks like it works:

```
. as {$info, $paths}
| .tags
| map(
    . as $tag
    | (.name |= "tag_" + gsub(" "; ""))
    | .value = {
        $info,
        tags: [ $tag ],
        paths: $paths | map_values(
            with_entries(select(IN(.value.tags[]; $tag.name)))
            | select(length > 0)
        )
    }
)
| from_entries
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reformulate this to [group by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73893818/112968) tags and then transform:

```
def group(k):
  group_by(k) | map({key:first|k, value:.}) | from_entries;

. as {$info}
| INDEX(.tags[];.name) as $tags # lookup table for tags by name
| .paths
| to_entries
| group(.value[].tags[]) # group paths by their tags
| with_entries(
    [$tags[.key]] as $tags
    | .key |= "tag_" + gsub(" "; "")  # fix property names
    | .value |= { $info, $tags, paths: from_entries } # transform to result
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a constructive solution that uses a helper function in the hope of making it digestible:

```
  # Input: an object { k1: { k21: { tags: [TAG ...] ... }, ...} }
  # Output: drop every key, k2, at the second level if k2.tags does not contain $tag
  def selection($tag):
    map_values(
      if type == "object" 
      then with_entries(
             select(.value | objects | select(.tags) | .tags | index($tag)))
      else .
      end );

  [range(0; .tags|length) as $i
   | (.tags[$i].name) as $tag
   | {"tag_\($tag|gsub(" ";""))": 
       { info,
         tags: [.tags[$i]],
         paths: (.paths | selection($tag ) | with_entries(select(.value != {})) )
       }
     } ] 
  | add
```