# Jq parse duplicate json file using jqplay.org

Tags: jq

Can I output the ip and source id only when source id is duplicate it should out put all ip in one array if no duplicate ip can be output with corresponding source id

```json
{"ip":"192.134.5.31","access_key":"223434354656767","source_id":"2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-87"}
{"ip":"172.23.54.4","saccess_key":"223434354656767","source_id":"2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-87"}
{"ip":"182,555,44.44","access_key":"223434354656767","source_id":"2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-222"}
```

I dont care about access key here also if this access key can be done with Jq would be great

```
unique_by(.ip) |{ip.source_id[]}
```

```
.ip| select(.source_id[])
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output? I'm having difficulty understanding the long sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `group_by` to group all the matching `source_id`.

Then you can create the desired output, for example:

```
group_by(.source_id)[] | { ip: map(.ip), source_id: (first.source_id) }
```

Will output:

```json
{
  "ip": [
    "182,555,44.44"
  ],
  "source_id": "2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-222"
}
{
  "ip": [
    "192.134.5.31",
    "172.23.54.4"
  ],
  "source_id": "2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-87"
}
```

Since

- We group on `source_id`
- We create an object for each group, containing
- An `map()` from all the lower ip's and the `source_id` taken from the `first` object

---

Use the `--slurp` option to combine those objects in to an array:

```
jq --slurp 'group_by(.source_id)[] | { ip: map(.ip), source_id: (first.source_id) }'
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-2G1blVLqo5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your expected output is, but if you are trying to group IPs by source id like such:

```json
{
  "2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-222": [
    "182,555,44.44"
  ],
  "2e74a68a-2fef-443544-815d-87": [
    "192.134.5.31",
    "172.23.54.4"
  ]
}
```

Then you can [group](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression)) by your source_id and then transform the output:

```
group_by(.source_id) | map({(.[0].source_id): map(.ip)}) | add
```

Or by using a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73893818/112968):

```
def group(k): group_by(k) | map({key:first|k, value:.}) | from_entries;
group(.source_id)  | map_values(map(.ip))
```

or

```
def group(k;v): group_by(k) | map({key:first|k, value:map(v)}) | from_entries;
group(.source_id;.ip)
```