# Swap key and array value, turning old keys into new array values, using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to invert the keys and values of some data where the values are arrays, such that every unique element of the value arrays becomes a key in the output, whose value is an array containing every input key whose value contained that element originally.

As an example, I've got some data like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "abc",
    "Contents": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "def",
    "Contents": [
      "foo",
      "baz",
      "ding"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "ghi",
    "Contents": [
      "bar",
      "dang",
      "baz"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    "abc",
    "def"
  ],
  "bar": [
    "abc",
    "ghi",
  ],
  "baz": [
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "ding": [
    "def"
  ],
  "dang": [
    "ghi"
  ]
}
```

I've tried the following, based on other questions on this site, but I'm stuck trying to avoid clobbering the results when using `reduce`. I know I'm close, I'm just struggling with dealing with the nested data.

```
map(.Id as $Id
  | .Contents
  | map({key: ., value: [$Id]})
  | from_entries
)
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)
```

The problem with this code is that, while it does return the data in the structure I want, it's clobbering the values. This is what it outputs right now:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    "def"
  ],
  "bar": [
    "ghi"
  ],
  "baz": [
    "ghi"
  ],
  "ding": [
    "def"
  ],
  "dang": [
    "ghi"
  ]
}
```

I've tried nesting `reduce` calls but to no avail, I'm just not comfortable with the syntax. I could handle this in other languages, but I'd really like to do it with jq. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with just `reduce`:

```
reduce .[] as {$Id, $Contents} ({}; .[$Contents[]] += [$Id])
```

```json
{
  "foo": [
    "abc",
    "def"
  ],
  "bar": [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "baz": [
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "ding": [
    "def"
  ],
  "dang": [
    "ghi"
  ]
}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/qSACI2lkcW3

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to get what was going on with the syntax here, but once I did, this solution worked well for me. My understanding is that basically it's saying "for each element in `$Contents`, update the accumulator object by doing `.element += [$Id]`." Hopefully I've got that right. At any rate, this works both with my toy example as well as the real-world data that I'm working with, and I can even use it on objects that have more than two keys. Thanks much.

Comment: Yes, that's it essentially. It can be useful to replace `reduce` with `foreach` when debugging to help visualize the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `group_by`:

```
map({ Id, Content: .Contents[] })
| group_by(.Content)
| map({ key: first.Content, value: map(.Id) })
| from_entries
```

If you are using the function definitions from [Reusable function to group_by but return an object with group as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893818/reusable-function-to-group-by-but-return-an-object-with-group-as-key), this can be simplified to:

```
map({ Id, Content: .Contents[] }) | group(.Content; .Id)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "bar": [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "baz": [
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ],
  "dang": [
    "ghi"
  ],
  "ding": [
    "def"
  ],
  "foo": [
    "abc",
    "def"
  ]
}
```