# Merging array of objects based on values in JQ

Tags: jq

I've created a JSON array that contains objects I want group and nest based on a shared value, and then have an array with a list of matching values under this. I just can't figure it out.

Here is my input data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "pcmp-ingestion-master",
    "s2iVersion": "4.5.0-05",
    "muleVersion": "4.5.0",
    "imageSha": "sha256:c1b618c6fbec2e2832824578a47893707ebea8a681bab1ce97b73b1a1e2fccb5"
  },
  {
    "name": "pcmp-ingestion-syst",
    "s2iVersion": "4.4.0-87",
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "imageSha": "sha256:c1b618c6fbec2e2832824578a47893707ebea8a681bab1ce97b73b1a1e2fccb5"
  },
  {
    "name": "pcmp-ingestion-uat",
    "s2iVersion": "4.4.0-87",
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "imageSha": "sha256:c1b618c6fbec2e2832824578a47893707ebea8a681bab1ce97b73b1a1e2fccb5"
  },
  {
    "name": "qualityofhire-uat",
    "s2iVersion": "4.4.0-85",
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "imageSha": "sha256:baabd127862667b17bda7ff278144314469205c12d1445295dc3cf0001ac79db"
  },
  {
    "name": "virtual-assist-uat",
    "s2iVersion": "4.4.0-85",
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "imageSha": "sha256:b82d58aa174fe668061e41453d11212e9162381f8b20a2db3b9a525e6b981140"
  }
]
```

Here is what I'd ultimately like to have as an output from JQ.

```
[
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.4.0-87",
      "4.4.0-85"
    ]
  },
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.6.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.6.0-01"
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried a few things but can only mange to map these down flat and select unique values, without combining them, like so:

```
map( { muleVersion: .muleVersion, "s2iVersions": ([.s2iVersion])}) | unique_by(.s2iVersions)
```

Which gives this output

```
[
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.4.0-85"
    ]
  },
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.4.0-87"
    ]
  },
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.6.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.6.0-01"
    ]
  }
]
```

I feel like the solution to this is probably blindingly obvious, but I'm in a rut. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group_by/1`, `map` and `unique`

```
group_by(.muleVersion) | 
  map({"muleVersion": .[0].muleVersion, s2iVersions: (map(.s2iVersion) | unique)})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after - thanks. I was trying group_by after my initial map, but seeing this way makes everything clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the ideas of [Reusable function to group_by but return an object with group as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893818/reusable-function-to-group-by-but-return-an-object-with-group-as-key):

```
def group(k;v):
  group_by(k) | map({ key: first|k, value: map(v) }) | from_entries;
def group(k): group(k; .);
  
group(.muleVersion; .s2iVersion)
| to_entries
| map({ muleVersion: .key, s2iVersions: (.value|unique) })
```

Or using `group_by` directly and mapping the result:

```
group_by(.muleVersion)
| map({ muleVersion: first.muleVersion, s2iVersions: (map(.s2iVersion)|unique) })
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.4.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.4.0-85",
      "4.4.0-87"
    ]
  },
  {
    "muleVersion": "4.5.0",
    "s2iVersions": [
      "4.5.0-05"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: OP wants to ignore duplicates I think

Comment: Thanks @knittl, the second example is great and adding a simple 'unique' function in the s2iVersion object did the job.

Comment: @Inian thanks, I missed that. Adapted with additional `unique` filter